# Add numbers at the top edge for each input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The code below will create a crosswords table by javascript function, but I need to add number for each box at the top-left edge for each box for simplicity for the user. How can I create numbers for all input boxes at the top left edge ?? any advice

I need the number at the edge of each box not as placeholder;  I need it fixed

```js
var currentTextInput;
var puzzelArrayData;
//Loads the Crossword puzzel
function initializeScreen() {
  var puzzelTable = document.getElementById("puzzel");
  puzzelArrayData = preparePuzzelArray();
  for (var i = 0; i < puzzelArrayData.length; i++) {
    var row = puzzelTable.insertRow(-1);
    var rowData = puzzelArrayData[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < rowData.length; j++) {
      var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
      if (rowData[j] != 0) {
        var txtID = String('txt' + '_' + i + '_' + j);
        cell.innerHTML = ' <input type="text" class="inputBox" maxlength="1" style="display:relative; font-size:16px;text-transform: uppercase; font-weight:700;" ' + 'id="' + txtID + '" onfocus="textInputFocus(' + "'" + txtID + "'"+ ')">';
        }
        else {
          cell.style.backgroundColor = "black";
        }
      }
    }
    addHint();
  }


  //Adds the hint numbers
  function addHint() {
    document.getElementById("txt_0_0").placeholder = "1";
    document.getElementById("txt_0_7").placeholder = "2";
//        document.getElementById("txt_1_5").placeholder = "3";
    document.getElementById("txt_4_5").placeholder = "8";
    document.getElementById("txt_6_0").placeholder = "6";
  }

  //Returns Array
  function preparePuzzelArray() {
    var items = [
      ['a', 0, 'e', 'n', 0, 'a', 'g', 'e', 0, 0, 'i', 0],
      ['t', 'r', 'y', 0, 'e', 0, 0, 'g', 'a', 'm', 'e', 's'],
      ['t', 0, 0, 0, 't', 'v', 0, 'g', 0, 'e', 0, 'i'],
      ['r', 'a', 0, 0, 0, 'i', 'a', 0, 0, 'm', 0, 'm'],
      ['a', 0, 0, 'a', 'u', 'd', 'i', 'o', 0, 'o', 0, 'p'],
      ['c', 0, 0, 's', 0, 'e', 0, 0, 0, 'r', 0, 'l'],
      ['t', 'e', 'c', 'h', 0, 'o', 'l', 'o', 'g', 'y', 0, 'e'],
      [0, 'l', 0, 'i', 0, 0, 'e', 0, 0, 0, 'e', 0],
      [0, 'i', 0, 'd', 'r', 'e', 'a', 'm', 0, 'c', 'a', 'n'],
      [0, 't', 'e', 'a', 'm', 0, 'r', 0, 'l', 0, 'r', 0],
      ['s', 'e', 'e', 0, 0, 'a', 'n', 'i', 0, 'a', 't', 'e'],
      ['o', 0, 'g', 'o', 0, 'h', 0, 0, 's', 0, 0, 0]
    ];
    return items;
  }
  window.onload = initializeScreen;
```

```css
tr {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

#leftBox {
  float: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#puzzel {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
}

.inputBox {
  width: 37px;
  height: 37px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="leftBox">
  <table id="puzzel">
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I created a snippet. Input 1.5 does not exist

Answer (score 2):

Add a span to the div you wrap around each input and style the span:

```js
var currentTextInput;
var puzzelArrayData;
//Loads the Crossword puzzel
function initializeScreen() {
  var puzzelTable = document.getElementById("puzzel");
  puzzelArrayData = preparePuzzelArray();
  for (var i = 0; i < puzzelArrayData.length; i++) {
    var row = puzzelTable.insertRow(-1);
    var rowData = puzzelArrayData[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < rowData.length; j++) {
      var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
      if (rowData[j] != 0) {
        var txtID = String('txt' + '_' + i + '_' + j);
        cell.innerHTML = '<div class="cell"><input type="text" class="inputBox"  maxlength = "1" style = "display:relative; font-size:16px;text-transform: uppercase;  font-weight: 700; " ' + 'id="' + txtID + '" onfocus="textInputFocus(' + "'" + txtID + "'" + ')">'+
        ' <span class="number">5</span></div>';
      } else {
        cell.style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
    }
  }
  addHint();
}


//Adds the hint numbers
function addHint() {
  document.getElementById("txt_0_0").placeholder = "1";
  document.getElementById("txt_0_7").placeholder = "2";
//      document.getElementById("txt_1_5").placeholder = "3";
  document.getElementById("txt_4_5").placeholder = "8";
  document.getElementById("txt_6_0").placeholder = "6";
}

//Returns Array
function preparePuzzelArray() {
  var items = [
    ['a', 0, 'e', 'n', 0, 'a', 'g', 'e', 0, 0, 'i', 0],
    ['t', 'r', 'y', 0, 'e', 0, 0, 'g', 'a', 'm', 'e', 's'],
    ['t', 0, 0, 0, 't', 'v', 0, 'g', 0, 'e', 0, 'i'],
    ['r', 'a', 0, 0, 0, 'i', 'a', 0, 0, 'm', 0, 'm'],
    ['a', 0, 0, 'a', 'u', 'd', 'i', 'o', 0, 'o', 0, 'p'],
    ['c', 0, 0, 's', 0, 'e', 0, 0, 0, 'r', 0, 'l'],
    ['t', 'e', 'c', 'h', 0, 'o', 'l', 'o', 'g', 'y', 0, 'e'],
    [0, 'l', 0, 'i', 0, 0, 'e', 0, 0, 0, 'e', 0],
    [0, 'i', 0, 'd', 'r', 'e', 'a', 'm', 0, 'c', 'a', 'n'],
    [0, 't', 'e', 'a', 'm', 0, 'r', 0, 'l', 0, 'r', 0],
    ['s', 'e', 'e', 0, 0, 'a', 'n', 'i', 0, 'a', 't', 'e'],
    ['o', 0, 'g', 'o', 0, 'h', 0, 0, 's', 0, 0, 0]
  ];
  return items;
}
initializeScreen();
```

```css
tr {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

#leftBox {
  float: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#puzzel {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
}

.inputBox {
  width: 37px;
  height: 37px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
}

.cell {
  position: relative;
}

.number {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  float: left;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="leftBox">
  <table id="puzzel">
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a background image:

```js
var currentTextInput;
var puzzelArrayData;
//Loads the Crossword puzzel
function initializeScreen() {
  var puzzelTable = document.getElementById("puzzel");
  puzzelArrayData = preparePuzzelArray();
  for (var i = 0; i < puzzelArrayData.length; i++) {
    var row = puzzelTable.insertRow(-1);
    var rowData = puzzelArrayData[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < rowData.length; j++) {
      var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
      if (rowData[j] != 0) {
        var txtID = String('txt' + '_' + i + '_' + j);

        cell.innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="inputBox" maxlength="1" style="display:relative; font-size:16px;text-transform: uppercase; font-weight:700;" ' + 
        'id="' + txtID + '" onfocus="textInputFocus(' + "'" + txtID + "'" + ')">';
        }
        else {
          cell.style.backgroundColor = "black";
        }
      }
    }
    addHint();
  }


  //Adds the hint numbers
  function addHint() {
   document.getElementById("txt_0_7").style.backgroundImage="url(data:image/gif;base64,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)"
    
  }

  //Returns Array
  function preparePuzzelArray() {
    var items = [
      ['a', 0, 'e', 'n', 0, 'a', 'g', 'e', 0, 0, 'i', 0],
      ['t', 'r', 'y', 0, 'e', 0, 0, 'g', 'a', 'm', 'e', 's'],
      ['t', 0, 0, 0, 't', 'v', 0, 'g', 0, 'e', 0, 'i'],
      ['r', 'a', 0, 0, 0, 'i', 'a', 0, 0, 'm', 0, 'm'],
      ['a', 0, 0, 'a', 'u', 'd', 'i', 'o', 0, 'o', 0, 'p'],
      ['c', 0, 0, 's', 0, 'e', 0, 0, 0, 'r', 0, 'l'],
      ['t', 'e', 'c', 'h', 0, 'o', 'l', 'o', 'g', 'y', 0, 'e'],
      [0, 'l', 0, 'i', 0, 0, 'e', 0, 0, 0, 'e', 0],
      [0, 'i', 0, 'd', 'r', 'e', 'a', 'm', 0, 'c', 'a', 'n'],
      [0, 't', 'e', 'a', 'm', 0, 'r', 0, 'l', 0, 'r', 0],
      ['s', 'e', 'e', 0, 0, 'a', 'n', 'i', 0, 'a', 't', 'e'],
      ['o', 0, 'g', 'o', 0, 'h', 0, 0, 's', 0, 0, 0]
    ];
    return items;
  }
  window.onload = initializeScreen;
```

```css
tr {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

#leftBox {
  float: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#puzzel {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
}

.inputBox {
  width: 37px;
  height: 37px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="leftBox">
  <table id="puzzel">
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a counter to have the total number of cells (see totalCells var in JS). 
And you need to insert that coutner in the html. That counter was added to your cell's innerHTML (please note the format of backtick style variable insertion). 
The input field and this new counter are placed within a relative positioned div, to then place the counter in the top-left corner with absolute position.

Here's a working pen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/opbpZm
and here's the html:

```
<div id="leftBox">
  <table id="puzzel">
  </table>
</div>
```

css:

```
tr {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

#leftBox {
  float: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#puzzel {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /*    border: 1px solid black; */
}

.inputBox {
  width: 37px;
  height: 37px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 0;
}


/* some changes */
.input_container {
  position:relative;
}
.input_counter {
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  left:2px;
  top:0;
  font-size:80%;
  font-weight:bold;
  z-index:100;
}
.input_container input {
}
```

js:

```
var currentTextInput;
var puzzelArrayData;
//Loads the Crossword puzzel
function initializeScreen() {
  var puzzelTable = document.getElementById("puzzel");
  puzzelArrayData = preparePuzzelArray();
  var totalCells = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < puzzelArrayData.length; i++) {
    var row = puzzelTable.insertRow(-1);
    var rowData = puzzelArrayData[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < rowData.length; j++) {

      var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
      if (rowData[j] != 0) {
        totalCells++;
        var txtID = String('txt' + '_' + i + '_' + j);
    cell.innerHTML = `<div class="input_container"><input type="text" class="inputBox" maxlength = "1" style = "display:relative; font-size:16px;text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: 700;" id="${txtID}"     onfocus="textInputFocus(${txtID})"><span class="input_counter">${totalCells}</span></div>`;
        }
        else {
          cell.style.backgroundColor = "black";
        }
      }
    }
    addHint();
  }


  //Adds the hint numbers
  function addHint() {
    document.getElementById("txt_0_0").placeholder = "1";
    document.getElementById("txt_0_7").placeholder = "2";
    document.getElementById("txt_1_5").placeholder = "3";
    document.getElementById("txt_4_5").placeholder = "8";
    document.getElementById("txt_6_0").placeholder = "6";
  }

  //Returns Array
  function preparePuzzelArray() {
    var items = [
      ['a', 0, 'e', 'n', 0, 'a', 'g', 'e', 0, 0, 'i', 0],
      ['t', 'r', 'y', 0, 'e', 0, 0, 'g', 'a', 'm', 'e', 's'],
      ['t', 0, 0, 0, 't', 'v', 0, 'g', 0, 'e', 0, 'i'],
      ['r', 'a', 0, 0, 0, 'i', 'a', 0, 0, 'm', 0, 'm'],
      ['a', 0, 0, 'a', 'u', 'd', 'i', 'o', 0, 'o', 0, 'p'],
      ['c', 0, 0, 's', 0, 'e', 0, 0, 0, 'r', 0, 'l'],
      ['t', 'e', 'c', 'h', 0, 'o', 'l', 'o', 'g', 'y', 0, 'e'],
      [0, 'l', 0, 'i', 0, 0, 'e', 0, 0, 0, 'e', 0],
      [0, 'i', 0, 'd', 'r', 'e', 'a', 'm', 0, 'c', 'a', 'n'],
      [0, 't', 'e', 'a', 'm', 0, 'r', 0, 'l', 0, 'r', 0],
      ['s', 'e', 'e', 0, 0, 'a', 'n', 'i', 0, 'a', 't', 'e'],
      ['o', 0, 'g', 'o', 0, 'h', 0, 0, 's', 0, 0, 0]
    ];
    return items;
  }
  window.onload = initializeScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure css, using a counter.

Increases on each cell and is used on "after" pseudoelement.

```
body{ counter-reset: hints; }
td{ counter-increment: hints; }
td{ position:relative;}
td::after{ content:counter(hints); position:absolute; left:0; z-index:1}
```

If you dont want to count the black cells change the increment from td to input:

```
input{counter-increment: hints; }
```

```js
var currentTextInput;
var puzzelArrayData;
//Loads the Crossword puzzel
function initializeScreen() {
  var puzzelTable = document.getElementById("puzzel");
  puzzelArrayData = preparePuzzelArray();
  for (var i = 0; i < puzzelArrayData.length; i++) {
    var row = puzzelTable.insertRow(-1);
    var rowData = puzzelArrayData[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < rowData.length; j++) {
      var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
      if (rowData[j] != 0) {
        var txtID = String('txt' + '_' + i + '_' + j);
        cell.innerHTML = ' <input type="text" class="inputBox" maxlength="1" style="display:relative; font-size:16px;text-transform: uppercase; font-weight:700;" ' + 'id="' + txtID + '" onfocus="textInputFocus(' + "'" + txtID + "'"+ ')">';
        }
        else {
          cell.style.backgroundColor = "black";
        }
      }
    }

  }



  //Returns Array
  function preparePuzzelArray() {
    var items = [
      ['a', 0, 'e', 'n', 0, 'a', 'g', 'e', 0, 0, 'i', 0],
      ['t', 'r', 'y', 0, 'e', 0, 0, 'g', 'a', 'm', 'e', 's'],
      ['t', 0, 0, 0, 't', 'v', 0, 'g', 0, 'e', 0, 'i'],
      ['r', 'a', 0, 0, 0, 'i', 'a', 0, 0, 'm', 0, 'm'],
      ['a', 0, 0, 'a', 'u', 'd', 'i', 'o', 0, 'o', 0, 'p'],
      ['c', 0, 0, 's', 0, 'e', 0, 0, 0, 'r', 0, 'l'],
      ['t', 'e', 'c', 'h', 0, 'o', 'l', 'o', 'g', 'y', 0, 'e'],
      [0, 'l', 0, 'i', 0, 0, 'e', 0, 0, 0, 'e', 0],
      [0, 'i', 0, 'd', 'r', 'e', 'a', 'm', 0, 'c', 'a', 'n'],
      [0, 't', 'e', 'a', 'm', 0, 'r', 0, 'l', 0, 'r', 0],
      ['s', 'e', 'e', 0, 0, 'a', 'n', 'i', 0, 'a', 't', 'e'],
      ['o', 0, 'g', 'o', 0, 'h', 0, 0, 's', 0, 0, 0]
    ];
    return items;
  }
  window.onload = initializeScreen;
```

```css
tr {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

#leftBox {
  float: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#puzzel {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
}

.inputBox {
  width: 37px;
  height: 37px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 0;
}

body{counter-reset: hints; }
td{counter-increment: hints; }
td{position:relative;}
td::after{content:counter(hints);position:absolute;left:0;z-index:1}
```

```html
<div id="leftBox">
  <table id="puzzel">
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: i need another help, after writing all the letter how can show a feedback message "completed", any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Changes made:

- Fixed your `cell.innerHTML`.
- Added a index counter to have increasing index numbers for each block. The variable is declared at the top `var index=1;` and increment using `index++`.
- The CSS added for the block and number is :

> ```
> .block {
>   position: relative;
> }
>
> .number {
>   position: absolute;
>   top: 0;
>   left: 0;
> }
> ```

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var currentTextInput;
  var puzzelArrayData;
  var index = 1;
  //Loads the Crossword puzzel
  function initializeScreen() {
    var puzzelTable = document.getElementById("puzzel");
    puzzelArrayData = preparePuzzelArray();
    for (var i = 0; i < puzzelArrayData.length; i++) {
      var row = puzzelTable.insertRow(-1);
      var rowData = puzzelArrayData[i];
      for (var j = 0; j < rowData.length; j++) {
        var cell = row.insertCell(-1);

        if (rowData[j] != 0) {
          var txtID = String('txt' + '_' + i + '_' + j);
          cell.innerHTML = "<div class='block'><input type='text' class='inputBox' maxlength = '1' style = 'display:relative; font-size:16px;text-transform: uppercase; font - weight: 700;' id=" + txtID + "onfocus= textInputFocus(" + txtID + ")> <div class='number'>" + (index++) + "</div></div>";
        } else {
          cell.style.backgroundColor = "black";
        }
      }
    }
    addHint();
  }


  //Adds the hint numbers
  function addHint() {
    document.getElementById("txt_0_0").placeholder = "1";
    document.getElementById("txt_0_7").placeholder = "2";
    document.getElementById("txt_1_5").placeholder = "3";
    document.getElementById("txt_4_5").placeholder = "8";
    document.getElementById("txt_6_0").placeholder = "6";
  }

  //Returns Array
  function preparePuzzelArray() {
    var items = [
      ['a', 0, 'e', 'n', 0, 'a', 'g', 'e', 0, 0, 'i', 0],
      ['t', 'r', 'y', 0, 'e', 0, 0, 'g', 'a', 'm', 'e', 's'],
      ['t', 0, 0, 0, 't', 'v', 0, 'g', 0, 'e', 0, 'i'],
      ['r', 'a', 0, 0, 0, 'i', 'a', 0, 0, 'm', 0, 'm'],
      ['a', 0, 0, 'a', 'u', 'd', 'i', 'o', 0, 'o', 0, 'p'],
      ['c', 0, 0, 's', 0, 'e', 0, 0, 0, 'r', 0, 'l'],
      ['t', 'e', 'c', 'h', 0, 'o', 'l', 'o', 'g', 'y', 0, 'e'],
      [0, 'l', 0, 'i', 0, 0, 'e', 0, 0, 0, 'e', 0],
      [0, 'i', 0, 'd', 'r', 'e', 'a', 'm', 0, 'c', 'a', 'n'],
      [0, 't', 'e', 'a', 'm', 0, 'r', 0, 'l', 0, 'r', 0],
      ['s', 'e', 'e', 0, 0, 'a', 'n', 'i', 0, 'a', 't', 'e'],
      ['o', 0, 'g', 'o', 0, 'h', 0, 0, 's', 0, 0, 0]
    ];
    return items;
  }
  initializeScreen();
});
```

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
}

.number {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

tr {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

#leftBox {
  float: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#puzzel {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
}

.inputBox {
  width: 37px;
  height: 37px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="leftBox">
  <table id="puzzel">
  </table>
</div>
```